# Is using System.identityHashCode(Obj) reliable to return unique Id

Tags: java, session, websocket, uniqueidentifier

I have a implementation of websocket in dropwizard service and theirs a need to implement session management on server side. On connection we get session object which is the communication link between client and server. But their is not way to get Unique id for session like **session.getId()** and i need id for session management.

So i have been thinking of using System.identityHashCode(Session) to get unique id and handle sessions using this ID.

just for reference the websocket onConnect structure is

```
@OnWebSocketConnect
public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException
{    
 // code to add the session in session management using unique id
}
```

So using **System.identityHashCode(Session)** will be good?

Comment: What is your session? A session cannot exist without some sort of unique identifier -- it is what defines a session as a session.

Comment: @Dunes Session represents an active link of communications with a Remote WebSocket Endpoint http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/Session.html

Comment: Will you be able to recreate a key without having access to the session? If not you might as well use a set to store your sessions rather than a map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

identityHashMap is usually derived from a memory address or a random number generator tied to a thread and then stored within the object header on first use by the JVM. The likelihood of collision is low, but not impossible.

Given that collisions can occur, why risk it? the bugs that this could lead to would be subtle and irritating to track down.

Comment: so theirs no way to get uniqueness for a object throughout its life till GC collects it

Comment: @Ninad The JVM does know uniqueness under the covers, see IdentityHashMap and the equality operator.  However it may just be simpler to generate and store a GUID with the object.

Comment: Completely as an aside, I believe that on the Oracle JVM the header bytes used for the identity hash code are the same bytes that are used for biased locking.  Which means that they cannot both be used, and so if one was to call identity hash code on an object and then use it in synchronized statements then the JVM would never be able to bias the lock towards that thread.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Session object itself might not persist outside of the method call. That is, for each method call a new Session object might be created and initialised with the same data as the old Session object. Meaning you could have the situation where multiple Sessions objects reference the same session, but have different memory addresses.

Answer (score 1):

`WebSocketSession` is the implementation of `Session`. It overrides `hashCode` and `equals` and so can be expected to be hashed safely in programs using more than 4GB of memory. That is, the session *is* the key.

You can do something like this:

```
class YourClass 
{

    private Set<Session> managedSessions = new HashSet<Session>();
    // or use a Map<Session,Data> if you want to store associated data

    @OnWebSocketConnect
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException
    {    
        if (managedSessions.contains(session)) {
            // working with preexisting session
        } else {
            managedSessions.add(session);
        }
    }

    @OnWebSocketClose
    public void onClose(Session session, int statusCode, String reason) 
    {
        managedSessions.remove(session);
    }

}
```

Comment: this is a bit off topic, but the requirement here is different their are two HashMaps, one with a machineId key and value as array of Id (i.e unique Ids of session) and second one is Id key and value session. So when ever data is recieved for a machine using first hashmap we will retrieve array of ids and using those ids send message to each session using second hashmap and on close use the id to remove session from second map and that id from that array of second map.

Comment: I don't understand the need for two maps. Why not just have the machine id link directly to its associated sessions. eg. `Map<MachineId,List<Session>>`  or `Map<MachineId,Set<Session>>`

Comment: ohh! thanks! i never a gave thot, went on with the previously implemented approach of previous system version by others