# Are the hashcodes returned by the System.identityHashCode method uniquely assigned to each object?

Tags: java, hashcode

Are the hashcodes returned by the System.identityHashCode method uniquely assigned to each object?

Since hashcode is an int and therefore the possible values ​​4,294,967,295, does the jvm guarantee at least one unique hashcode for every object within such a quantity of objects?

Comment: What do you mean by *"uniquely assigned to each object"*?

Comment: What does the [api](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)) tell you?

Comment: Hash codes are not unique by definition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is using System.identityHashCode(Obj) reliable to return unique Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910094/is-using-system-identityhashcodeobj-reliable-to-return-unique-id)

Comment: More formally, they map a large domain onto a much smaller range.

Comment: If you're just looking for a unique Id (and don't really care about hashCodes), why not get the current Time as a `long` in nanoseconds?  Just don't get more than one per nanosecond.

Comment: For performance reasons I need this id to be assigned by the JVM because otherwise I would have to create a map where to keep all the objects and their ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pigeonhole principle applies.

If you have 4 pigeon holes, and 5 pigeons which must all find a pigeon hole to roost in, then at least one pigeon hole is going to have more than one pigeon in it.

Obvious, right?

Same applies here. There are only `2^32` different <s>pigeon holes</s> hash codes (because the value is an `int`, int in java is defined as a 32-bit number, thus, only 2^32 different possible values exit). That is a big, big number. about 4 billion.

However, there is nothing in the java spec that decrees that no more than 4 billion <s>pigeons</s> objects can ever exist. If ever more than 4 billion objects exist, no algorithm one could possibly design could ever promise uniqueness, because of this principle. QED.

NB: You can also use the pigeonhole principle to prove that a universal compressor (a tool that can compress anything, guaranteeing that the compressed result is always smaller or equal) cannot exist, as long as it actually compresses anything, then there must as a consequence be some stream of bits for which the compressor actually produces a *larger* file. You can use it to prove that `(int) (Math.random() * 10)` is not quite uniform random, and why you should therefore use `random.nextInt(10)` instead (which is). It's a surprisingly useful principle to prove things in computer science!

Now, one could imagine an `int` based coding system which promises unique codes *until* you hit 4 billion unique objects, but making such a promise is incredibly complicated and itself a memory hog, if it would have to work for any and all objects.

Java makes no such promises, and `System.iHC` is as a consequence not guaranteed to have either unique numbers (completely impossible to make that promise) nor that `System.iHC` has 'perfect' distribution (hashcodes as distributed as they could be, i.e. no reuse until 4 billion objects exist simultaneously). Note that 'exists' is already complicated: When does an object truly 'disappear'?

In practice, iHC is based on memory positions; it's distribution is very very good. But there is a difference between **it is highly unlikely any 2 objects would ever have the same identity hashcode** and **we guarantee no two objects share an identity hash code**.

Comment: So the new question is: since hashcode is an int and therefore the possible values ​​4,294,967,295, does the jvm guarantee at least one unique hashcode for every object within such a quantity of objects?

Comment: As I already said in the bolded section at the end: No, the JVM does not guarantee it.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not unique for all objects. It all depend on your JVM implementation. You can only be sure only that for same object this method returns same value.

Comment: Yes they are. All depends on jvm.

Comment: @K.Vääräniemi - can ALL strings have a unique `int` ? A string can have lot of bits, an `int` *only* 32 bits - or just consider a `Long` that have 64 bits, the first 2^32 may have an unique hash code but than all unique `int`s  were consumed and there must be repetition

Comment: This is not even JVM specific.  It is guaranteed that if you allocate enough objects and get their identity hashcodes you will eventually get a collision.

Comment: @user85421 in a runtime java process we can have at maximum of 2.147.483.647 objects?

Comment: @K.Vääräniemi not sure where you got that, I just wrote a program that created `Long`s from 0 to 4_294_967_295 (`Integer.MAX_VALUE*2L+1L`)  ((and calculated the XOR-checksum of their identity hash code to avoid JIT deletion)) (((maybe I made something wrong, but I doubt there is such a limit, lots of server programs would need constant restarting)))

Comment: @K.Vääräniemi - That assertion is false.  (Or if it was a question, the answer is no.)   There is no such limit on the number of Java objects.  The actual  technical limits are 1) the limit of 2^64 on unique references, and 2) the amount of virtual memory needed to hold the JVM representations of the objects, etcetera.  And this is only a limit on the number of object that are live at any given point in time.  There is no bound on the number of objects that may exist over time.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, rather than reserve space for object's identity hash code, at least some version of the JVM reserve a couple bits in the object's header that indicate which of three conditions applied:

1. The identity hash code has not yet been examined.
2. The identity hash code has been examined, and the object has not been moved since then.
3. The identity hash code was examined, and then the object was moved.

Getting the identity hashCode when an object is in state #1 will change it to state #2 and return a value derived from the object's address.  Getting the identity hashCode when an object is in state #2 will simply perform that same computation on the address.

If an object in state #1 needs to be relocated, it will simply stay in state #1.  If an object is relocated when it's in state #2, the system will make a copy which has an extra four bytes reserved for the hash code, compute a hash code based on the old address, and store it in those reserved bytes, and mark the object as being in state #3.  After that, any attempt to read the hash code will report the saved value.

If an object is created and then either relocated or destroyed, the space it previously occupied will likely be used at some time in the future to hold a new object.  Such an object may very well have the same address as the old one; if it does, the identity hash code will likely match.

Note that the hashCode function isn't expected to be good enough to avoid all collisions, but merely good enough to turn a large number of comparisons into a small number.  If a hash code can reduce the number of comparisons from 10,000 to 10, that's a much bigger win than reducing the number of comparisons from 10 to 1 would be.